# External mercurial repository in redmine?

Tags: mercurial, redmine

Is this possible to have external mercurial repository in redmine just like svn?

For svn i've got following configoration options and it work with external repos:
[image]

For mercurial i can only enter local path to repository:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, you will need a local clone as stated in the [Redmine documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories#Mercurial-repository):

> Mercurial repository
>
> To synchronize with a Mercurial
>   repository, you will have to have a
>   local clone of the repository on the
>   same server you have Redmine installed
>   on. Let's say you put Redmine in
>   /var/www/redmine.example.com/www and
>   have put your mercurial repository in
>   /var/www/sources.example.com/repo/example,
>   you would have to select Mercurial as
>   a SCM, then enter
>   /var/www/sources.example.com/repo/example
>   in the repository text box.

A similar [question](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/17283) has been asked in the Redmine forums. You'll need to set up a local clone and update it automatically, e.g. by using a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job.

Comment: Is there any way to have this repo autoamticly updated when somebody pushes to 'main' repo?

Comment: I know there is `post-push` hook but it does not seem to be possible to set up in bitbucket :/

Comment: @seler if you have a follow up question you should ask it in a new question -- it's both correct _and_ you'll get more respondants.  No one new is going to look at this question which @Luke correctly answered.